# Connecting Android mobile device via adb over network (2/3/4G )

Tags: android, adb

We can start ADB over tcp-ip and then we can connect to device on wifi network but can we connect the same  device  using mobile network ?

> So my question is can we connect  Android ADB  via network (2/3/4G )?
> and if yes then how ?

Comment: Dont think so as mobile providers usually do not forward connection requests to mobile devices.

Comment: Somehow this guy is able to do so in following video https://youtu.be/NgPxoCpNbJU?t=44

Answer (score 1):

You can turn on mobile hotspot on your device and connect your PC to it's WiFi network. Then use
`adb connect 192.168.43.1`
to connect to the device. This is the default IP address of a hotspot (if device vendor didn't change it).

Comment: No the device is not available with me. It's remotely available.